# How can I prevent HTML local file opening when script is executed?

Tags: python, html, plotly

I have created a local html plotly graph which I intend to run from a server, every time the script ends it opens the html, is there something I can use which will prevent this happening?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! Just looking at script, find in the end line, where plotly draw a plot. It should look such this:

```
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

And add parameter `auto_open` and specify it to `False`:

```
plotly.offline.plot(fig, auto_open = False)
```

Hope it helps!